# Troubleshooting MySQL error - Form, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Could someone please explain why this is giving me the following error?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' )' at line 1

I tried re-creating without all the junk Dreamweaver adds, but I don't totally understand how to submit a form and have it pass the variables to my query. And the code Dreamweaver is so confusing to me, I can't figure out what I can remove without breaking the whole program.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/hh.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO data_customer (first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_hh, $hh);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $hh) or die(mysql_error());

$cid = mysqli_insert_id();

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO data_phone_number (phone_number) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['phone_number'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_hh, $hh);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $hh) or die(mysql_error());

$pid = mysqli_insert_id();

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO join_customer_phone (customer_id, phone_id) VALUES ($cid, $pid)");
  mysql_select_db($database_hh, $hh);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $hh) or die(mysql_error());

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
 <table align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
   <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">First_name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
   <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Last_name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
   <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Phone_number:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" value="" size="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
   <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Print the resulting query being executed with an echo or something. Surely it's something unexpected resulting in a faulty sentence.

Comment: Hmmm...you mean, just replace sprintf( with echo? Sorry, I'm learning. It's so discouraging to run into snags like this. Every example I can find just deals with many-to-one relationships; I can't find anything for using a form for many-to-many relationships. Can anyone refer me to tutorials on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try:

```
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO data_customer (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('" . 
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text") . "', '" .
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text") .  "';";
```

If it doesn't work then put your `%s`s in 'these' brackets. I know for sure that you should put values in those brackets.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnyPHP - I'm trying every which way with both suggestions, but still getting errors. Are those single quotes or those other things that look like single quotes?

Comment: The global rule: anything after `=` should be in single quotes. The ones, that are right near enter button. If you are still getting errors, `var_dump()` your query and you will 100% see the problem. You may also show your query here.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing mysql functions with mysqli functions. Stick to mysqli (as mysql is deprecated).

Comment: Regardless, the two shouldn't be mixed, and mysqli is more future-proofed.

Comment: totally agree... I was just trolling, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks, @asmecher - Yeah, I'm using old books and old Dreamweaver to learn.

Comment: No problem. My guess is that your final query -- the join_customer_phone insert -- is coming up broken because the IDs couldn't be fetched, but as Alfabravo suggested, if you dump your queries before/as you execute them, you'll know which one is the culprit and how it's broken.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. The other two tables update fine when I remove the junction query. I don't know how to dump, though. Do you know where I can find a working example or tutorial that uses a form to update a many-to-many relationship? I think I'm really just going to need an example for this and I can't find one for the life of me. It seems like this would be critical for any database driven website, so it's beyond me why there isn't more info about this = /

Comment: First problem is to solve your mysql_ and mysqli_ mix; that may well solve the problem. If you want to dump your queries, just use:

    echo(htmlentities($insertSQL));

just before you execute each query.

Comment: Ok, I added the dump and it confirms the first two tables are updated and they are, but nothing shows for my junction query. I updated to mysqli_, too and still no dice.